# C#: WCF Interface implementing another interface to expose methods

Tags: c#, interface

I have another question related to this so please read it if you need any further detail. This is a more specific question relating to one element of the other question. I have an interface which describes a dao. This interface is implemented by another interface which will be the interface for a wcf service. The reason being that coincidentally all the functions in the parent interface need to be exposed via a wcf interface. The parent interface does not contain wcf attributes because it does not need them. The child interface needs wcf attributes in order to work as a wcf interface. The wcf interface may eventually contain more methods that arent in the parent interface. There are two ways I can think of to get these attributes on the child interface which are as follows:

1. Decorate the parent interface methods with the attributes.
2. Override all the methods from the parent interface in the child interface and then decorate these methods with the attributes.

Would solution 1 actually work? Meaning would the wcf attributes be inherited by the child(wcf) interface and be available as part of the service contract? Is this bad practice?

Would solution 2 be a good idea? It seems counter productive to override all the methods simply to decorate them with wcf attributes.

Comment: side note: I would worry a bit about this design; it mixes internal and external dependencies. Are you sure of the design? Any change to the base, internal, interface will be forced on the descendant, public, interface. Is that what you want/need? I would never add the attributes to the base interface because they have no function there.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure of the interface inheritance design however all the public functions contained in the dao are required to be exposed via a wcf service which means the two interfaces are identical. Would you suggest it is a better idea to forget about the inheritance altogether and treat them as seperate entities despite them being so similar? The wcf interface may eventually not be the same in that it may contain more functions as well as those in the dao interface. I thought by using inheritance I could force the wcf interface to make sure it exposes all the public dao functions.

Comment: Also if you have any ideas with regard to how this should be done if you think the design is wrong then by all means please do tell me as I would like to hear them. My other question may help you understand the structure of my solution.

Comment: In general services either expose a SERVICE type of API: operations that do a lot of work and operate on large sets of data or, expose a RESOURCE type of API: such as a RESTFul API. In both cases I prefer these operations to be independent of the underlying technology. An internal interface will probably contain technology specific parameters and types; I want the services to be free of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution **#2** is the better one.

It might seem counter-productive, but it's actually logical: you have an interface with some methods which perform some tasks, and you add on top of it another 'layer' which exposes them in whatever way you need to.

This way, if you want to no longer expose the methods via WCF but, let's say, you want to make it a RIA service, or you want to replace it with a fake client, you just switch the 'upper' layer and change the overrides. The underlying, actual interface doesn't need to even be aware of this.

It all resorts to attaching the "wires" (the parent interface) to the correct "display" (the child interface).

Comment: Thanks. Thats a good explanation. So keep it as it is in terms of implementations and then override the parent methods and decorate thenm with the wcf attributes?